# Geometry drawing and manipulation options for Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, graphics, silverlight-4.0, 2d

I am looking for options for drawing and manipulating geometry in Silverlight.  I've looked at LiveGeometry which is a little overkill for the job.

Requirements:

- 8-point scaling using mouse
- Rotation
- Drag and drop
- Drawing of Rectangle, Elipse,   Polygon and Polyline with the mouse

I would like links to the library and a brief description of it's merits if you have used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve most of the above using Adorners. [This one](http://nokola.com/blog/post/2009/12/13/Adorners-in-Silverlight-Move-Size-Rotate-Custom-Mouse-Cursor.aspx) has rather nice defaults.

You should also have a look at [Argentum Tela](http://www.damonpayne.com/agt/) (and [links to blog posts explaining design decisions](http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/2012/01/08/silverlight-designer/)).

However, I'm not aware of any library that allows you to edit polylines.